# useNavigate not working react-router-dom v6 but works when i press a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Im using `react-router` v6, the `useNavigate()` hook, nothing happens when I run it in a function. I see my console log output.

If I press the button, it navigates successfully. How do I get the `navigate()` to work in the logic part of the code?

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

function Loading() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  getAuth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user === null) {
      navigate('/signin')
    } else {
      console.log('i see this in the console')
      navigate('/dashboard')
    }
  })

  return (
    <Button onClick={() => navigate('/home')}>Press button</Button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`navigate` should be called from a lifecycle hook, e.g. `useEffect`, or a callback, like the button element's click handler. The current code is calling `getAuth` as an unintentional side-effect. Don't forget to unsubscribe the auth listener when the component unmounts.

```
function Loading() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = getAuth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user === null) {
        navigate('/signin');
      } else {
        console.log('i see this in the console');
        navigate('/dashboard');
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <Button onClick={() => navigate('/home')}>Press button</Button>
  );
}
```